# Dispatcher has no subscribers error after upgrading spring-cloud version from Camden.SR4 to Camden.SR5

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-rabbit, spring-cloud-stream

MyCode:
   1.ChannelInterface

```
 public interface MessageChanelInterface {

        String DEVICE_SINK = "device-sink";

        @Input(DEVICE_SINK)
        SubscribableChannel receiveDeviceEvent();}
```

---

2.Listener

```
@Service
public class SubscriberToDevice {

      @Autowired
      ParkingService parkingService;

      @StreamListener(MessageChanelInterface.DEVICE_SINK)
      public void receiveDeviceEvent(Object event) {
          //Some code what to do with event.
      }
}
```

---

3.Chanell Binding

```
@Configuration

   @EnableBinding(MessageChanelInterface.class)

   public class MessageChanelConfiguration {

}
```

---

4.Broker binding and channel configuration

```
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit1.type=rabbit
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit1.environment.spring.rabbitmq.addresses=${_rabbit.host}
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit1.environment.spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit1.environment.spring.rabbitmq.username=${_rabbit.username}
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit1.environment.spring.rabbitmq.password=${_rabbit.password}
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.device-sink.binder=rabbit1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.device-sink.destination=device
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.device-sink.group=group-${spring.application.name}
```

---

---

While I use spring-cloud version Camden.SR4 no error message, when receive some message. After I upgrade to version Camden.SR5 after received message I got this error message. Publisher I have configured and he publish message without errors. By the way publisher configuration is:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.device-source.binder=rabbit1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.device-source.destination=device
```

Is some big change in Brooklyn.SR2 (version spring.cloud.stream in spring cloud Camden.SR5) with subscriber configuration?  Because publisher work good. I didn't see any changes in subscriber configuration in description of spring.cloud.stream Brooklyn.SR2. Some solution how to fix it?

ERROR MESSAGE

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:877)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:787)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:707)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:98)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:189)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:276)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:172)
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy195.invokeListener(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1236)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:688)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1190)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1174)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1200(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:98)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'parkingspace:default:8096.device-sink'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=EventOccupationDetected [parkingSpaceID=141AA061-86C4-8518-03EC-39C0F6F99AE0], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=device, amqp_receivedExchange=device, amqp_deliveryTag=1, correlation-id=85687a94-9bcd-48bb-bfc4-765546b32996, amqp_consumerQueue=device.group-parkingspace, amqp_redelivered=false, id=01d247a7-b37b-2d79-4b90-f59812d25f4b, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-qSSn_-Zw481_KxEz-pbjUQ, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=sk.posam.sp.device.domain.event.EventOccupationDetected, timestamp=1490874431951}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:93)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:70)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:64)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$400(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$1.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:95)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:784)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:154)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I believe there is a fix in Camden.SR6

Comment: Camden.SR6 doesn't work too. At first I try Camden.SR6, because I have 1.4.5.RELEASE version of spring boot and recomended spring cloud version for this spring boot is Camden.SR6. However version Camden.SR6 and Camden.SR5 doesn't work correct for me.

Answer (score 1):

There's a known regression between Brooklyn.SR1 and Brooklyn.SR2 due to some internal refactoring.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/844

One workaround ATM would be to use a different argument type than `Object` (we kind of recommend that anyway, in order to get the benefits of type coercion).

As this has been found after Brooklyn.SR3, probably it makes sense to wait until Brooklyn.S4 or a later version of Camden that picks that up. Alternatively, you can consider upgrading to Chelsea.RC1 which has just been released (planning a release for it on Monday, to be picked up in Dalston.RELEASE in Spring Cloud).

EDIT: Quick note on upgrading the version to Chelsea - it requires Boot 1.5 so YMMV there.